# c++ overloading the [] operator without a class

Tags: c++

I have created a structure:

```
struct a{
   int a1;
   int a2;
   int a3;
};
```

Is there any way to create a function where `a[1]` will give access to `a1` in the same way that I'll be able through an array?

Edit, I have pasted the part that I actually do:

```
struct lipid{
  particle mainPart;
  bead * head;
  bead * body;
  bead * tail;
  vec direction;
  bead * operator[](int index){
    switch(index){
    case 0: return head;
    case 1: return body;
    case 2: return tail;
    default: return body;
    }
  }
};
```

bead and particle are another struct I have created. It works... thanks

Comment: A `struct` is a class, it can overload `[]` as well as any class overload. But why not use `typedef int a[3]` if you simply want three integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by delnan, you can use methods on structures, just like classes.

So:

```
struct a{
   int a1;
   int a2;
   int a3;
   int &operator[]( int i ){ 
       switch(i){
       case 1: return a1;
       case 2: return a2;
       case 3: return a3;
       default: return -1
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns the structure type and not what I want. I have edited my message for my actual code, never mind I have found my error.

Answer (score 4):

Last line of Section 11.8 (Operator Overloading, Subscripting) in Stroustrup's 'The C++ Programming Language':

```
 'An operator []() must be a member function.'
```

So, no, this is not possible in C++.

(Though of course a `struct` is a `class` in C++, but I assume you mean you want `struct a` to remain a POD)

Comment: `a` would still be POD even with an `operator[]`, as long as it's not virtual.

Comment: @Steve: Please see my solution. I would like to know your comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `operator [] must be a member function`, as noted by others, you cannot do that.

But I came up with the following wrapper class called `subscriptable` which might help you *simulating* it:

```
class subscriptable
{
  A & a;
  public:
    subscriptable(A & a) : a(a) {}
    subscriptable(const subscriptable & s) : a(s.a) {}
    int & operator[](int i)
    { 
       if ( i < 0 || i > 2 ) throw "index out of range";
       else if ( i == 0 ) return a.a1;
       else if ( i == 1 ) return a.a2;
       else return a.a3;
    }
    operator A & () { return a; }
};
void print(A & a)
{
   subscriptable s = a; //a implicitly converts to subscriptable
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) 
       std::cout << s[i] << std::endl;
}
int main() 
{
        A a;
        subscriptable s = a; //a implicitly converts to subscriptable
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) 
             s[i] = (i + 1) * 100;
        print(s); //s implicitly converts to A
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
100
200
300
```

Online Demo : http://www.ideone.com/ymmg1

Comment: Seems reasonable if we're not allowed to modify the definition of `a`, although I'd probably use an array of `int*` rather than a vector. Depending on expected use you might want to make it assignable (so either use a pointer rather than a reference to `s` so that it's a reseatable reference, or else implement a copy `operator=` to copy through to the underlying struct, whichever semantics you want).

Comment: @Steve: I realized that I don't even need `int*`. My updated version seems better than the previous one. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you must, you can work around it with a union, though you may get frowned upon:

```
union
{
    struct
    {
        int a1;
        int a2;
        int a3;
    };
    int a[]; // may need compiler-specific tweaking
};
```

Note that not all compilers support `int a[]`, you may have to write `int a[0]` or even `int a[3]`, depending on compiler/language dialect.

Comment: And I wouldn't be too surprised if this went into implementation-specific territory (using one part of a union after another one has been assigned), although you should be save unless the compiler does some really nasty layout trickery.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it is not the nicest thing in the world, and one had better a good explanation at hand when someone else gets to read the code :-)  But no kidding, I've actually used such a construct at times, for example it works like magic to bulk-load function pointers from a DLL in a loop (such as when writing your own OpenGL/OpenAL/OpenCL loaders).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `struct a` is in some library and you are unable to change it because otherwise you would have taken @delnan's `typedef` suggestion (`typedef int a[3]`).

If the struct isn't used polymorphically you could abuse inheritance and add the operator yourself:

```
struct a_with_brackets : public a
{
    int& operator[](int index)
    {
        switch(index)
        {
        case 1 : return a1;
        case 2 : return a2;
        case 3 : return a3;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Mark... See my solution. I would like to know your comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct a{
   int a1;
   int a2;
   int a3;

   int & operator[]( int i ) {
      if ( i == 0 ) {
         return a1;
      }
      else if ( i == 1 ) {
         return a2;
      }
      else if ( i == 2 ) {
         return a3;
      }
      else {
         throw "index error";
      }


};
```